Java Data Collector for Stack Overflow
This application collects data from Stack Overflow using the Stack Exchange API.
It retrieves questions, answers, and comments related to Java programming for analysis.
Features include:

Collecting data for Java-tagged threads.
Analyzing user engagement.
Visualizing data in a web interface.

